# Using $_GET in PHP include with variable in the include URL

Tags: php, variables, get, include, odbc

Firslty, please forgive the ineloquent phrasing of my question.

What I am trying to do, is create a simple odbc script, and store it in a file which will be included in my main PHP file several times with different variables.

When including them, I want to specify some variables to pass to it.

My example would be:

Main page

```
include("table-fields.php?table=sometable");
```

table-fields.php

```
$table = $_GET['table'];
odbc_exec(some database function WHERE TBL= $table);
```

However, if my understanding is correct, as $_GET is global, it would be looking for main.php?table=

Would the better choice be to just set the variable before including, e.g.:

```
$table = some table;
include("table-fields.php");
```

table-fields.php

```
odbc(some database function WHERE TBL= $table);
```

I want to try and avoid that if possible.

Thanks, Eds

Comment: `$table = $_GET['table'];
odbc_exec(some database function WHERE TBL= $table);` should work...

Comment: May be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998705/url-querystring-with-a-php-include

Comment: Reading a file from your hard disc is an entirely different operation than downloading a file from the Internet. Perhaps you're confused because `include()` can actually do both things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When including a file, the contents of that file is outputted into the current file, it's not requested with HTTP, so all you need to do is :

```
$table = "sometable";

include("table-fields.php");
```

and in the included file, just use the variable :

```
odbc(some database function WHERE TBL= $table);
```

as the included content would work just like if you wrote it in the main file etc.

Comment: The odd thing is, that in another page on our site, I have a script to get a user image from the database. This is done in the same way, where I include("getimage.php?id=x"). Then, inside that script, I have a $_GET['id'] which then queries the database. This works for all IDs. The only difference, is that at the end of that script, I set the header("type: image/jpeg") and then echo the content. Is it possible to do something similar in this case? Thanks

Comment: @Eds - The point is, you don't have to use the querystring to get data when using PHP includes, and you should'nt, as the included file will be part of the including file. You only need querystrings when using anchors etc on your page to request an image based on the ID etc, not when doing includes.

Comment: Ok no problem. I suppose it's neater to do it this way anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable before the include and it will be available in the code under it.

`$_GET` is used to get data from HTTP request.

As you pointed out, this would be the correct way:

```
$table = some table;
include("table-fields.php");
```

Just imagine the `include` as a copy and paste inside your code. The code inside the included content will be replazing the `include` call.