# I am getting include failed to open stream error on PHP include with variable

Tags: php

I am having issues trying to call a php script from another php script with an include. I am passing "keysum" as a variable and have verified that is the case. The include statement is failing with the following error. I am pretty new to php and need to call different programs one for warehouse summary and one for account summary based on the radio button selected.

> PHP Warning:  include failed to open stream: No such file or directory  referer:
>
> PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening

As you see from my code below I have tried many different ways of doing the path.

Here is the include statement loop.

```
if($_POST['xltype'] == 'keysum') {
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `file_get_contents()` or similar instead? `include` is for local files on the same server.

Comment: These are all on the same server but for some reason it is not finding the program. I've tried it with the path in the include and without.

Comment: include`keyacctspread.php` with out the `?` ... your saying fthe file name is `keyacctsum.php?cust=001990R00` when its not

Comment: If you want to pass a value through your `include`, set a variable before you include the file and reference that in the other script. If its not including, and giving you warnings - the path is wrong and you must use the right one. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much I used $_REQUEST['cust'] = $cust; then the 
  include "keyacctspread.php"; and that worked great.

Comment: Is `include "keyacctspread.php?cust=$cust";` the one that is failing or the `https` one? For `include "keyacctspread.php?cust=$cust";` you could do `$_GET['cust'] = $cust; include "keyacctspread.php";` Then the `GET` is set when that file is accessed. If you need to you could `unset` it after the `include`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't include a query string in an `include()` php won't let you.

If it's two separate servers, you should not be using includes anyway.

This question is answered here: 
[URL querystring with a php include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998705/url-querystring-with-a-php-include)

Comment: You can use a query string if you include from HTTP(s), but not from the filesystem.