# how to use a snippets id in wordpress to a another post using include/require

Tags: php, wordpress

Include function, not working in WordPress plugin woody snippets

I have 2 woody snippet files.

- 1st - dbconfig
- 2nd - check database connection

I want to use dbconfig file in check database connection file.

I tried using the id `[wbcr_php_snippet id="25"]` but it not working.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Some other options I tried:

```
include('wbcr_php_snippet id="25"');
```

and also used

```
include('wp-admin/post.php?post=25');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL querystring with a php include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998705/url-querystring-with-a-php-include)

Comment: its showing  include(): Failed opening 'wp-admin/post.php?post=25'

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? `include` is running purely server-side, while adding an ID to the URL needs a real HTTP request

Comment: give me suggesstions how its possible ? after that it will work.

Comment: i working on localhost wordpress.